Issues with Cloud-Init user setup
I am trying to setup a headless ubuntu server so that in init a rdp would be setup so that I can connect to the Remote Desktop right away after the boot process is complete.
I found that this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/use-remote-desktop?tabs=azure-powershell, works well if I do the setup manually but now I am trying to automate this using cloud-init.
For this I am passing following .yaml as user data to my cloud provider:
#cloud-config

package_update: true

users:
  - default
  - name: xrpd
    groups:
      - xrdp
      - ssl-cert

packages:
  - xfce4
  - xrdp
  - net-tools

runcmd:
  - [ systemctl, enable, xrdp ]
  - [ echo, xfce4-session, >~/.xsession ]
  - [ systemctl, restart, xrdp ]
  - [ ufw, allow, 3389 ]

power_state:
  mode: reboot
  message: rebooting after initial setup
  timeout: 30
  condition: True

Update works and packages are installed, xrdp is enabled etc. However, the user 'xrdp' is not set to be a part of a ssl-cert group and I fail to see why?
Thanks for the help!

Got it working now, thanks to falcojr for hints. Here is the working version:
#cloud-config

package_update: true

packages:
  - xfce4
  - xrdp
  - net-tools

write_files:
  - path: /root/.xsession
    content: |
      xfce4-session
    
runcmd:
  - [ adduser, "xrdp", "ssl-cert"]
  - [ systemctl, enable, xrdp ]
  - [ systemctl, restart, xrdp ]
  - [ ufw, allow, "3389" ]

power_state:
  mode: reboot
  message: rebooting after initial setup
  timeout: 30
  condition: True

So the first thing is that I ditched the user setup and I just use runcmd, I use adduser instead of usermod, seems to work.
Another thing was replacing the 'echo xfce4-session >~/.xsession' command. Since this actually writes 'xfce4-session' to a hidden file, I replaced it with just write_files.
Cheers!

Cloud-init's users_groups module runs before the package_update_upgrade_install module so the ssl-cert group does not exist when the xrpd user is getting created.
A workaround could be to add something like this to your runcmd:
  - "usermod -a -G ssl-cert xrpd"

Also note that your current yaml is technically invalid. Every sub-array should only contain strings and neither >~/.xsession nor 3389 are strings. After being fixed, your runcmd could look something like:
runcmd:
  - "usermod -a -G ssl-cert xrpd"
  - [systemctl, enable, xrdp]
  - [echo, xfce4-session, ">~/.xsession"]
  - [systemctl, restart, xrdp]
  - [ufw, allow, "3389"]


Thanks for the answer. I was suspecting the same thing myself about the execution order. However the fix you proposed does not work for me, for some reason the firewall rule is added but especially the 'echo xfce4-session >~/.xsession' command bothers me why it does not work.
First command does not run either but I am suspecting it is only a syntax issue.
